# Unable to get access token and refresh token for Google Drive oauth

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have developed a Java web application to integrate google drive with our platform. From today in the morning I am seeing a strange issue while making a call for getting access token and refresh token, I started getting

**Error:**

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error [Vary: X-Origin, Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8, Date: Fri, 17 Apr 2015 18:06:25 GMT, Expires: Fri, 17 Apr 2015 18:06:25 GMT, Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff, X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN, X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, Server: GSE, Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1, Accept-Ranges: none, Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding, Transfer-Encoding: chunked]

When ever I make a call to get access or refresh tokens

Currently I am following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) and I am using 
"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token" to get access tokens, this app is developed quite a while back and till yesterday I was working fine with out any issues,

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(config.getAccessTokenUrl());
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic ");

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("code", authCode));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", config.getClientId()));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", config.getClientSecuret()));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("redirect_uri", config.getRedirectUrI()));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "authorization_code"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity sendentity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
        httpPost.setEntity(sendentity);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        if (response != null && response.getEntity() != null) {
```

That is the code I am using to get access token and using below code to get refresh token.

```
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(config.getAccessTokenUrl());
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic");

        List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("refresh_token", refreshToken));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", config.getClientId()));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", config.getClientSecuret()));
        parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "refresh_token"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity sendentity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters);
        httpPost.setEntity(sendentity);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);

        if (response != null && response.getEntity() != null) {
```

How can I fix this issue ASAP, it's in production

Comment: I would suggest you go to Oauth Playground, and tick the gear to enter your own credentials. Then you can go through the auth flow. Make a note of the http requests and compare them to what your app is sending. How is your app authenticating the user?

Comment: @pinoyyid I found the issue, google doesn't like the header I am sending httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic"); I am using this for more than a year and never had issues, it started returning 500 from Friday, not sure what's changed on google side. Google playground is useful, just now I went through that. Thanks for suggesting, will debug my future issues with that

Comment: I guessed that was the problem. Google have just deprecated everything but OAuth2 so only bearer tokens are supported.